# Pancake and increasing order

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, sorting

Determine the number of 5 pancake stacks that requires 
exactly 2 flips to put into the increasing order, i.e., 1,2,3,4,5. 
(Example: 3,4,2,1,5 is one of them.)

Comment: Do it backwards. Starting from a sorted stack there are _at most_ $4\times 4$ ways to do two nontrivial flips. Do any of them end up in the same configuration?

Comment: I could not get it